# History of the definition of completeness of algebraic varieties (and properness of morphisms)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ho.history-overview

An algebraic variety (say over an algebraically closed field) $X$ is  *complete*  if for every variety $Y$, the projection $X \times Y \to Y$ is closed (with respect to the Zariski topology).

As it is well known, the motivation for this definition comes from the observation that it is equivalent to compactness of topological spaces (under some reasonable conditions - e.g. if every point of X is the intersection of countably many open neighborhoods).

What is the history of this definition?

Comment: Complete varieties are defined in Weil's *Foundations* (1946), as a generalization of projective varieties. I doubt that they appeared before.